# Pass std::vector as const float *?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, dynamic-arrays

My function is:

```
void function(const float *, int sizeOfArray){...}
```

My vector is:

```
std::vector<float> myVector(size, val);
```

I read in the docs you can use myVector[0] as standard c++ static arrays operations.

How can I pass that vector to that function **without having to copy the values to a new dynamic array**? (I want to avoid using new / delete just for this).

Is it something like...?

```
function(myVector[0], size);
```

I'm using C++11 by the way.

Comment: `function(myVector.data(), size);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [std::vector::data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) (since C++11) to get the pointer to the underlying array.

> Returns pointer to the underlying array serving as element storage. The pointer is such that range [data(); data() + size()) is always a valid range, even if the container is empty (data() is not dereferenceable in that case).

e.g.

```
function(myVector.data(), myVector.size());
```

> Is it something like...?
>
> ```
> function(myVector[0], size);
> ```

`myVector[0]` will return the element (i.e. `float&`), not the address (i.e. `float*`). Before C++11 you can pass `&myVector[0]`.

Comment: `&myVector[0]` can be used in all versions of C++, not just before C++11.  `myVector.data()` can also be used in C++11 and later.

Answer (score 1):

```
function(myVector.data(), myVector.size());
```